# Como quebrar ao final da linha checkBox

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, quebras-de-linha

Os cursos estão saindo sem formatação, existem mais cursos e nem estão aparecendo na tela de cadastro.

[image: Cursos da tela]

Como quebrar isso em XHTML?

Código:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
<p:outputLabel value="Cursos" for="cursos" />
                <p:selectManyCheckbox id="cursos" styleClass="many-checkbox" value="#{cadastroCicloBean.ciclo.cursos}" 
                    converter="cursoConverter" required="true" requiredMessage="Por favor, informe a data de Inicio">
                        <f:attribute name="collectionType" value="java.util.ArrayList"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroCicloBean.cursos}" var="curso" itemLabel="#{curso.nome}" itemValue="#{curso}" />
                </p:selectManyCheckbox>     
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o Grid Layout definindo o número de colunas ou usar o responsive layout (também com o número de colunas).

```
<h3>Grid Layout</h3>
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="grid" value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities}" layout="grid" columns="3">
    <f:selectItems value="#{checkboxView.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>

<h3>Responsive (since v5.2.4)</h3>
<p:selectManyCheckbox id="grid2" value="#{checkboxView.selectedCities2}" layout="responsive" columns="3">
    <f:selectItems value="#{checkboxView.cities}" var="city" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
</p:selectManyCheckbox>
```

Fonte: [Primefaces Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/manyCheckbox.xhtml)

Comment: Perfeitamente amigo. Thank you!